# Sentence case conversion with java

Tags: java, string

What is the best way to implement the sentence case conversion in java

For Example:
today is monday. yesterday was sunday. tuesday comes after monday

output would be 
**T**oday is monday. **Y**esterday was sunday. **T**uesday comes after monday

My logic is:

- Convert the whole sentence to lower case letters.
- Check for `'.'` and convert the first character to CAPITAL letters after `'. '`

Comment: sounds sane, assuming your sentences don't contain names or acronyms

Comment: This is really an algorithm question, not a Java question; the approach is what you are asking for, and the implementation is a minor detail

Comment: I wish you would've used Friday instead Monday in the example. Then we could make Rebecka Black jokes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic looks fine. A bit more code:

- `sentence.split("[\\.?!]")` would give you an array of sentences (splitting on punctuation marks
- include special cases for abbreviations like 5 min.
- don't convert to lowercase - you may lose the capitalization of proper names
- Turn the first letter of each sentence to upper-case (trim any whitespaces before that)

Comment: This may not work for non-English languages / scripts, which is a serious limitation of this answer. Unfortunately, I don't know a solution that does work for all languages, short of using a library like ICU4J. Which you probably should be doing anyway instead of trying to re-implement this and get many cases wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Except for abbreviations like e.g. or a 3 lb. weight -- these will get you into trouble, and there isn't a great way to automatically detect sentence beginnings. (note: abbreviations can be proper names too, like N.Y. for New York so there isn't an exhaustive list)

You also need to use ? and ! as sentence delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for you:

```
String input = "today is monday. yesterday was sunday. tuesday comes after monday";
StringBuffer buffy = new StringBuffer(input); // You may want to .toLowerCase() - up to you
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^|\\.)\\s*(\\w)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(buffy);
while (matcher.find())
    buffy.replace(matcher.end() - 1, matcher.end(), matcher.group(2).toUpperCase());
System.out.println(buffy); // Today is monday. Yesterday was sunday. Tuesday comes after monday
```

The regex `(^|\\.)\\s*(\\w)` matches on either start of line or dot, followed by optional whitespace, then a word character.

Comment: nice, additional punctuation characters (!, ?) may be added in the first group of the regex and a `toLowerCase()` may be added if needed

Answer (score 0):

Look at [StringCharacterIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/StringCharacterIterator.html). You iterate until find a dot (or other separator), then look for the next letter (might be some spaces/newlines until you get to it) and make it upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
StringBuilder txt = new StringBuilder("today is monday. yetserday was sunday. tuesday comes after monday");
int pos = -1;
do
{
    txt.replace(pos + 1, pos + 2, txt.substring(pos + 1,pos + 2).toUpperCase());
    pos = txt.indexOf(".", pos) + 1;
}
while(pos > 0 && pos < txt.length());
System.out.println(txt.toString());
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Today is monday. Yetserday was sunday. Tuesday comes after monday
```

Comment: What if the input string is empty - wouldn't that throw an exception?