# Looking for easy way in java to uppper case only the first letter of a string

Tags: java

Looking for easy way in java to change only the first letter to upper case of a string.

For example, I have a String `DRIVER`, how can I make it `Driver` with java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329611/sentence-case-conversion-with-java

Comment: If you have Apache `commons-lang` as a dependency already then [`WordUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Springs so I can do:

```
String d = "DRIVER";
d = StringUtils.capitalize(d.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: so why do you ask then?

Comment: i did not know the anwser until I found it

Comment: Rather than post your own answer which just duplicates one of the existing answers, you should accept one of them.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
String d = "DRIVER";
d = d.substring(0,1) + d.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Edit:

see also [StringUtils.capitalize()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize%28java.lang.String%29), like so:

```
d = StringUtils.capitalize(d.toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Actually `d.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + d.substring(1).toLowerCase()`, but the trick is clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
WordUtils.capitalize(string);
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "DRIVER";
String strFirst = str.substring(0,1);
str = strFirst + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String txt = "DRIVER";
    txt = txt.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + txt.substring(1).toLowerCase();            
    System.out.print(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CapitalizeFully()`

```
String s = "DRIVER";
WordUtils.capitalizeFully(s);
```

`s` would hold `"Driver"`

`capitalize()` **only** changes the first character to a capital, it doesn't touch the others.

I understand `CapitalizeFully()` changes the first char to a capitol and the other to a lower case.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully(java.lang.String)

By the way there are lots of other great functions in the Apache Commons Lang Library.